# is there anyone who can help R Error in while (x <= 100) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r

```
x = 0
while (x <= 100){
  x = x + sample(1:6,1,replace = F)
  ladder.bottom = c(1,4,9,21,28,36,51,80)
  ladder.top = c(38,14,31,42,84,44,67,100)
  chute.bottom = c(6,11,19,24,26,53,60,73,75,78)
  chute.top = c(16,49,62,87,47,56,64,93,95,98)
  w = which(ladder.bottom == x)
  t = which(chute.top == x)
  if (length(w) >= 0){
    x = ladder.top[w]
    print(x)
  }else if (length(t) >= 0){
    x = chute.bottom[t]
    print(x)
  }else {
    print(x)
    next
  }
}
```

it returns

> ```
> [1] 14
> numeric(0)
> Error in while (x <= 100) { : argument is of length zero
> ```

and I do not know why

Comment: The error is coming because  the line `x = ladder.top[w]` does not return a number if there is no matching value in the given vectors. So the `x` will have a value `numeric(0)` which can't pass in the subsequent `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

In `if (length(w) >= 0)` and `else if (length(t) >= 0)`, replace `>=` by `>`.

Comment: You want to exclude cases, in which no matches `w = which(ladder.bottom == x)` and `t = which(chute.top == x)` are found. In these cases, `length(w)` and `length(t)` both equal `0`, so require `>0`.